# Как вырезать текст между скобочками в php

Tags: php

Есть текст. В нем есть скобки. Как вырезать текст в этих скобках и поместить его в в массив? Т.е. каждое слово между скобок `(` и `)` должно стать элементом массива. И если мы добавим еще скобки, то текст между ними должен тоже автоматически вырезаться в массив. Регулярки использовать нельзя. Нужно как-то циклом наверное... Но не получается. Заранее благодарю за любую подсказку.
На выходе результатом должен быть не один массив, а из каждого отрезка текста между скобочками чтобы создавался отдельный массив с элементами из слов. Например:

```
Array(2){
[0]=>'Уважаемые' 
[1]=>'клиенты'}
```

Вот текст:

> $y='(Уважаемые клиенты)! У некоторых пользователей могут быть
>   трудности с отображением полисов ДМС (в личном кабинете). Спешим вас
>   заверить, что все ваши полисы - действительны (и на их актуальность
>   это не повлияет). В настоящее время мы работаем над проблемой
>   отображения. (Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства).';

Comment: тестовое задание?

Comment: Начните с [этого](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.strings.php)

Comment: Ну да. Задание. Функции работы со строками я знаю. Как найти вхождение строки, вырезать, создать массив - это все понятно. Но как сделать это все в цикле, чтобы было не важно какой текст между скобочками, чтобы можно было его менять, убирать, добавлять новые скобочки и все работало. И без регулярок! Вот это не получается....

Comment: простите но это какой то вынос мозга когда делается все просто на регулярке, кто вам такой умный дал такое задание? и кстати за минус я вам больше не буду помогать!

Comment: @Genesis, ну такое задание. Сначала нужно без регулярок научиться, а потом наверное можно и по правильному. Такое вот оно есть. И надо с ним что-то делать. Это не я его придумала. Текст, правда, поменяла. И главное - простите за минус! Я даже не заметила как его вам поставила. Пыталась убрать, но он остается. Вчера был мой "дебют" - впервые решила таки задать вопрос и была удивлена, что так быстро ответили.Минусы от новичков как я не засчитываются, впредь буду внимательнее. Это мне урок. А вы меня простите!!!

Comment: @GENESIS Забудьте и двигайтесь дальше, делая мир лучше своими ответами. Чем больше Вы даете хороших ответов, тем лучше у Вас репутация и с течением времени, при большой репутации Вы перестанете обращать внимание на минусы если таковые будут.

Comment: @GENESIS а если минус Вам был поставлен по ошибке и тот кто его поставил хочет его убрать, но не получается, внесите правку в свой ответ, после чего в течении некоторого времени можно изменить свой голос, например убрать минус.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text='(Уважаемые клиенты)! У некоторых пользователей могут быть трудности с отображением полисов ДМС (в личном кабинете). Спешим вас заверить, что все ваши полисы - действительны (и на их актуальность это не повлияет). В настоящее время мы работаем над проблемой отображения. (Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства).';
$array = [];
$start = null; $end = null;

foreach(range(0, strlen($text)) as $index){
    $symbol = mb_substr($text, $index, 1, 'UTF-8');
    if($symbol == "("){
        $start = $index+1;
    }
    if($symbol == ")"){
      $end = $index;
      $str = mb_substr($text, $start, ($end - $start), "UTF-8");
      array_push($array, explode(" ", $str));
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Уважаемые"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "клиенты"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "в"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "личном"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "кабинете"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "и"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "на"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "их"
    [3]=>
    string(24) "актуальность"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "это"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "не"
    [6]=>
    string(16) "повлияет"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "Приносим"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "извинения"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "за"
    [3]=>
    string(24) "доставленные"
    [4]=>
    string(20) "неудобства"
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает. А может сможете подсказать как сделать так, чтобы это все был не один массив, а из каждого отрезка текста между скобочками создавался отдельный массив с элементами из слов. Например: Array(2){[0]=>'Уважаемые' [1]=>'клиенты'}

Comment: @ОлисияМедведева дополните свой вопрос, как должен выглядеть на выходе результат

Comment: @ОлисияМедведева обновил код

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Answer (score 0):

> *Как вырезать текст в этих скобках и поместить его в в массив?*

1. Получаете в цикле первый символ из строки
2. Если первый символ - открывающая скобка, активируете переключатель `$switch = 1;`
3. Если переключатель активен `$switch == 1`, сохраняете текущий символ в массив
4. Если текущий символ - закрывающая скобка, деактивируете переключатель `$switch = 0;`
5. Полученный массив объединяете по словам, и разбиваете по предложениям.

---

```
$y = '(Уважаемые клиенты)! У некоторых пользователей могут быть трудности с отображением полисов ДМС (в личном кабинете). Спешим вас заверить, что все ваши полисы - действительны (и на их актуальность это не повлияет). В настоящее время мы работаем над проблемой отображения. (Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства).';

$new = [];
$switch = 0;
$strlen = mb_strlen($y);

while ($strlen) {
    $first = mb_substr($y, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
    $y = mb_substr($y, 1, $strlen, 'UTF-8');
    $strlen = mb_strlen($y);
    $first != '(' ?: $switch = 1;

    if ($switch == 1 && $first != '(') {
        if ($first == ')') {
            $switch = 0;
            $new[] = '^';
        } else {
            $new[] = $first;
        }
    }
}

$tmp = trim(join($new), '^');
$new = explode('^', $tmp);

print_r($new);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Уважаемые клиенты
    [1] => в личном кабинете
    [2] => и на их актуальность это не повлияет
    [3] => Приносим извинения за доставленные неудобства
)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Разбираюсь.

Comment: @ОлисияМедведева успехов )

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен конечный автомат (которым, кстати и являются регулярные выражения). Перебираете символы. Если встретили один из ключевых - скобка открывающаяся или закрывающаяся, то в первом случае переключаете автомат в режим накопления фразы в скобках, а во втором выходите из этого режима запомнив то что накопилось.

Это частный простой случай. В общем случае автомата у вас была бы матрица переходов - из какого состояния в какое можно перейти при каких условиях. Так можно было бы распарсить что угодно сложное. Например, математические выражения и формулы.

```
$y = '(Уважаемые клиенты)! У некоторых .. ДМС (в личном кабинете). Спешим .. действительны (и на .. повлияет). В настоящее .. отображения. (Приносим .. неудобства).';

$found = [];
$word = "";
$eat = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($y); $i++) {
    $ch = $y[$i];
    if ($ch === "(") {
        $eat = true;
    } elseif ($ch === ")") {
        $eat = false;
        $found[] = $word;
        $word = "";
    } elseif ($eat) {
        $word .= $ch;
    }
}
var_dump($found);
```

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  [0] => string(33) "Уважаемые клиенты"
  [1] => string(32) "в личном кабинете"
  [2] => string(27) "и на .. повлияет"
  [3] => string(40) "Приносим .. неудобства"
}
```